# What is the running time of comb sort?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, big-o, time-complexity

According to me, [Comb sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_sort) should also run in sub quadratic time just like shell sort. This is because comb sort is to bubble sort just how shell sort is related to insertion sort. Shell sort sorts the array according to gap sequences applying insertion sort and similarly comb sort sorts the array according to gap sequences applying bubble sort. So what is the the running time of comb sort?

Comment: Its worst case is quadratic, according to the references in the Wiki article. Does that answer your question? Because if not, then I think you asked the wrong question

Comment: I didn't notice the table at the right on the wiki page at first. But yes, it now answers my question. Thanks.

Comment: Comb-sort is weird; pay attention to the *average case* which is the "expected running time". Empirical benchmarks on comb sort and quick/merge sorts are fun; how can one little sort even try and keep up?

Comment: I compared [combsort for 5000 elements](http://codepad.org/2UUBNSJj) v/s [combsort for 500 elements](http://codepad.org/zHBAG6vZ). Although worst case is quadratic, but it may surprise you with its figures for random cases, execution time, practical usability for sorting large data set and .... its simplicity.

Comment: @NiklasB. : I think you should rewrite your comment as answer.
so SO mark this question as answered.

Comment: This question on cstheory references an Omega(n^2) lower-bound on the runtime of comb sort: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9619/analysis-of-comb-sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(This question has been unanswered for a while, so I'm converting my comment into an answer.)*

Although there are similarities between shell sort and comb sort, the average-case runtime of comb sort is O(n<sup>2</sup>). Proving this is a bit tricky, and the technique that I've seen used to prove it is the [incompressibility method](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~paulv/papers/sorting.pdf), an information-theoretic technique involving Kolmogorov complexity.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

With what sequence of increments?

If the increments are chosen to be: the set of all numbers of the form (2^p * 3^q), that are less than N, then, yes, the running time *is* better than quadratic (it's proportional to N times the square of the logarithm of N).  With *that* set of increments, Combsort performs *exactly* the same exchanges as a Shellsort using the same increments (the "Pratt sequence").  But that's not what people usually have in mind when they're talking about Combsort.

In theory...

With increments that are decreasing geometrically (e.g. on each pass over the input the increment is, say, about 80% of the previous increment), which is what people usually mean when they talk about Combsort... yes, asymptotically, it *is* quadratic in both the worst-case and the average case.  But...

In practice...

So long as the increments are relatively prime and the ratio between one increment and the next is sensible (80% is fine), n has to *astronomically* large before the *average* running time will be much more than n.log(n). I've sorted hundreds of millions of records at a time with Combsort, and I've only ever seen quadratic running times when I've deliberately engineered them by constructing "killer inputs".  In practice, with relatively prime increments (and a ratio between adjacent increments of 1.25:1), even for millions of records, Combsort requires on average, about 3 times as many comparisons as a mergesort and typically takes between 2 and 3 times as long to run.